# using pow function in an expression

Tags: c++, function, pow

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

// Defining Variable

using namespace std;

const int MONTHS_IN_YEAR = 12; 
const int PURCHASE_PRICE= 123500;
const int AMOUNT_MORG= 111150;
const int DOWN_PAYMENT =  12350;
const float MONTHLY_RATE= 0.542f;
const float FORMULA_RATE=1.542f;
float PAYMENT;
int main()




{

PAYMENT= (float)(MONTHLY_RATE*AMOUNT_MORG)*(pow(1.542,180));
cout << PAYMENT;

cout <<  fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);


system ("cls");
cout <<"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"; 
cout <<'$';
cout << setw(79)<<'$';
cout<<'$';
cout << setw(79)<<'$';
cout << '$';
cout << setw(79)<<'$';
cout << '$'<<"      " <<"Welcome to the mortgage information calculator 2013"
<<"                     " << '$';
cout <<'$';
cout << setw(79)<<'$';
cout<<'$';
cout << setw(79)<<'$';
cout <<'$'<< "     "<< " Made exclusively for Dewey,Cheatum and Howe bankers"
<<"                     "<<'$';
cout <<'$';
cout << setw(79)<<'$';
cout<<'$'<<"      "<< "by: Steven Fisher"
<<"                                                       "<<'$';
cout <<'$';
cout << setw(79)<<'$';
cout<<"$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$"<<endl; 

system ("pause");




return 0; 

}
```

So here is my code. I'm new to the C++ language and I was assigned a project in class and I have to calculate the monthly payment for a house mortgage.

I need to use the `pow` function and multiply the power by an expression. Here's what I tried:

```
(float)(MONTHLY_RATE*AMOUNT_MORG)*(pow(1.542,180))
```

and when I run the program I get an answer of `1.#inf`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your numbers are just extremely large. If you use `double` instead of `float`, you can still compute it in this particular case (I tried). But clearly, there is something wrong about the numbers and the formulae or how you use them. Not really a C++ problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.542<sup>180</sup> is more than 7,164,522,793,368,325,816,802,274,738,448,555.  That's a pretty big number, are you sure it fits in your floating point type?

Based on your comments below, it looks like you want to be using 1.00542.  You have several other copies of that information that are wrong too (`MONTHLY_RATE`, `FORMULA_RATE`).

Comment: Even if it fits, it definitely beats even the worst of the short term loan sharks that advertise on TV with "2570% APR".

Comment: Actually you'd want to use `1.0542` for a 5.42% rate; for example, `pow(1.0542, 10)` would correspond to 10 years at that rate. But 5.42% is far too high for a *monthly* rate. Either it's 5.42%/year, and you need to divide by 12 to get the monthly rate, or it's something like 0.542%/month.

Comment: i had a APR of 6.5 divided by 12 to get a monthly interest rate of 0.54166666666666666666666666666667 which i rounded 0.542. this is the formula i'm suppose to be using  monthly payment= monthly interest(purchase - down payment)* (1+monthly interest)^180 which is months in a year which i'm using 15 years / (1 + monthly interest)^years in months - 1. or P= 1(T-D)*(1+I)^M/(1+I)^m -1.

Comment: That should be 0.065 divided by 12, then.

Comment: @Keth - yes - I was looking at his `MONTHLY_RATE` there.  Definitely a DRY problem in this code.

Comment: Thanks for the help Carl, I can't believe I didn't catch that.